# Ruby on Rails: Implementing search. How should I format my route for many parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, routes

I'm building my first Ruby on Rails application, and I want to do it the "Rails" way, making my application as RESTful as possible.

The application revolves around a search function, in which a user fills out a form defining what they are looking for, submits it, then pages through their results, viewing items they are interested in. From my understanding of REST, it sounds like I should be encoding my parameters into the URL for my results page(?)

If my base route is:

`match "search" => "search#index"`

And the base route for my search results are:

`match "search/results" => "search#results"`

What would be the best way of implementing routes/URLs/parameters for my search? The solution must:

- Support many parameters (30+), of which, any could be optional.
- Support pagination: there could be alot of results.
- Adhere to the "Rails way"!

Any suggestions/tips from you Rails pros would be very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pagination: you can use a gem like `will_paginate` or `kaminari`

Concerning search parameters: Rails will put anything in the request's query string into a `params` variable accessible within your controllers and views.

What you're trying to do (naming the urls search & search/results) doesn't really align with "restful routes". Still, this is what you've asked for.

```
scope :search do 
  get 'search' => 'search#index' 
  get 'search/results' => 'search#show' 
end
```

will produce

```
  search GET            /search(.:format)                search#index
  search_results GET    /search/results(.:format)        search#show
```

To remain restful, try discerning what you're searching for... for products, the results would be displayed using `Products#index`.

If you want to keep the search broad, I'd suggest `Search#new` and `Results#index`.  These latter options seem more RESTful.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but I need some clarification. Say I pursue the separate `Results#index` controller,.. would I then use my `Search#new` to build a restful query string, to be used in a url like `results?varA=1&varB=2...&varN=30`?

Comment: That's right. There should exist a form somewhere (like at `/search/new`) that submits to `/results`. Whether your search form is one field or 100 fields, each named field should be represented as a key/value pair in the `params` hash (access it in Results#index).

Answer (score 0):

As you are probably anticipated, passing those 30 params around as url parameters is probably not the best approach.
I would consider creating a Configuration model (and table) for them and focus on the form being able to update this model.  This will make storing the searches, doing multiple searches, validating the searches much easier in IMHO.  Use this model in conjunction with the actual model, to do the searches.

For the pagination, as rthbound says use [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki) or [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari).